# What's the difference between a buffio.Scanner and a text/scanner.Scanner?

Tags: io, go

What's the difference between [scanner.Scanner](http://golang.org/pkg/text/scanner/#Scanner) from package [text/scanner](http://golang.org/pkg/text/scanner/),
and a [bufio](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/).[Scanner](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner)?

Comment: Not sure why this is being down voted, it's a legit question.

Comment: BTW don't use text/scanner unless you really want to parse source code.

Comment: I see the distinction now, but I don't see why the pckage wasn't something like code/scanner, or had a higher level of abstraction, like generating an ast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`text/scanner`](http://golang.org/pkg/text/scanner/#Scanner) is more optimized for reading source code, mostly Go source:

> By default, **a Scanner skips white space and Go comments and recognizes
>   all literals as defined by the Go language specification**. It may be
>   customized to recognize only a subset of those literals and to
>   recognize different white space characters.

Comment: Note, `text/scanner` is really only good for scanning whitespace separated tokens, while `bufio` can use arbitrary separators via custom `Split` function

Answer (score -4):

The documentation seems to explain pretty clearly.

**text/scanner**

> A Scanner implements reading of Unicode characters and tokens from an
>   io.Reader

**bufio**

> Scanner provides a convenient interface for reading data such as  a
>   file of newline-delimited lines of text.